# ASP.NET MVC 5 database update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I was initializing my website Users and Roles data in `IdentityConfig.cs` file and when I added a new model than mapping it to the database using code-first add-migration and update-database command, I get an empty database:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    // Create User=aadmin2018@mail.com with Admin2018@mail.com in the Admin role
    public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        const string name = "admin2018@mail.com";
        const string password = "Admin2018@mail.com";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        // Create role Admin if it does not exist
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);

        if (role == null)
        {
            role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        var user = userManager.FindByName(name);

        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = name,
                Email = name,
                FirstName = "Admin",
                LastName = "Admin",
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1),
                Address = new Address
                {
                    AddressLine1 = "1 Admin Street",
                    Town = "Town",
                    County = "County",
                    Postcode = "PostCode"
                }
            };

            var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }

        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);

        if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name))
        {
            var result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
        }

        // Create users role
        const string userRoleName = "Users";
        role = roleManager.FindByName(userRoleName);

        if (role == null)
        {
            role = new IdentityRole(userRoleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }
    }
}
```

What should I change to the code so those data return to the database?

Comment: The Up() code of your migration is blank? Does your ApplicationDbContext inherit from IdentityDbContext?

Comment: Yes my ApplicationDbContext inherit from IdentityDbContext, the Up() code of my migrations contains the creation of all tables and they are blank in the database without the values specified in the code snippet posted above

Comment: Have you tried deleting the database? Initializer Seed() will only run when you change your model or there is no database. There is a different Seed() method for migrations that runs every time you do update-database.

Comment: Can you specifiy the name of File/Folder that are you referencing.

Comment: Your seed will only run upon database creation, not update-database. See here https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/